# Selecting high altitude points for training samples

Tags: arcgis-10.3, dem, land-cover

I am creating training samples for land cover classes in ArcGIS 10.3, and I need to define mountain areas as land that is over a certain height.

How can I do this?

(I have tried drawing polygons over the areas color coded to be over 600m altitude in my DEM, but I worry that this is irrelevant as the spectral signatures of these mountain areas will be similar to other land cover classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reclassify DEM, you can set specific value for example 1 for cells which are above given value (height) and 0 for other cells.

Next if you want you can convert raster into vector